# Street address cannot contain more than 2 lines -- payment page

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, shipping-address

I changed shipping street address values 2 in the admin panel. Now I can't place order only for logged in users. It's working fine for not logged in user.

If I changed it into 3 lines of the street it's working fine.But not working for 2 lines.

for more details : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13766

Kindly help me.

advance thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an existing customer has 3 street address line when our customer configuration street line number 3, then we change the configuration and those customers getting this error. To delete the existing street address and add a new address.

Answer (score 3):

This query will change from 3 lines to 2 lines. It will change the first 'new line' to ', '.

to view,

```
SELECT insert(street, locate('\n', street), length('\n'), ', ') from customer_address_entity where length(street) - length(replace(street, '\n', ''))>1;
```

To update

```
update customer_address_entity set street= insert(street, locate('\n', street), length('\n'), ', ') where length(street) - length(replace(street, '\n', ''))>1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Better option is to convert 3 line street data to single line then update the config.

Hope this below query helps

To check

```
select entity_id, street, replace(street,'\n',',') as street_new from customer_address_entity;
```

To update

```
update customer_address_entity set street = replace(street,'\n',',');
```

Answer (score 1):

All the previous answers are correct, but, to get and update only the customers/addresses which generates issues I suggest you to include a WHERE `statement`.

**Get affected customers/adddresses:**

```
SELECT 
    entity_id, parent_id, street, replace(street,'\n',',') as street_new 
FROM 
    customer_address_entity 
WHERE 
    street LIKE '%\n%'
ORDER BY 
    parent_id DESC;
```

**Fix them massively:**

```
update customer_address_entity set street = REPLACE(street,'\n',',') WHERE street LIKE '%\n%'
```

Doing this, you will put the address in a single line changing the line breaks by commas.